# Is there any MATLAB function similar to semidefinite() from Python cvxpy package?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization, cvx

```
import cvxpy
from cvxpy import semidefinite
semidefinite(12,'S')
```

gives:

```
Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (12, 12))
```

Is there any similar function in MATLAB (2021a)?

Comment: You found a function which you don't understand and ask for a similar function in some  other environment? What are you doing?

Comment: Sorry that is not my question, I edited it out. I am asking for a similar function in Matlab I know there are multiple convex optimization toolboxes.

Comment: Well.. there is only one DCP-based (where those expressions come from) and you already tagged it. Everything more makes not much sense without context and is also off-topic here.